# python parsing a file and extract paragraphs

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, parsing

I'm using a home tool that parses the computer configuration to verify if some basic configuration is applied or not and if not, it generates an alert in a textfile on the host on which I run the tool.

The tool don't make a file by computer that don't work but a file for all.

I'd like to parse this text file and get each paragraphs corresponding to each computer to send an email to IT whose in charge of the computer to tell him what he has to do.

For example below:

```
---- mycomputerone ---- 

 Hello

 During Test of mycomputerone following misconfiguration were detected
 - bad ip adress
 - bad name

 please could take the action to correct it and come back to us?

 ---- mycomputertwo ---- 

 Hello

 During Test of mycomputertwo following misconfiguration were detected
 - bad ip adress
 - bad name
 - administrative share available

 please could take the action to correct it and come back to us?

 ---- mycomputerthree ---- 
.....
```

I'd like to get the text between `hello` and  `?` but can't manage how to do it

I tried

```
re.search(r'hello'(S*\w+)\?'), text)
```

It didn't work. I read the file via

```
d = open(file, 'r'; encoding="UTF-8") 
text = d.read()
```

Comment: Have you tried any pattern yet? How are you reading in the file? Why not read it line by line, check if a line starts with `---` and then add the subsequent lines to a current record?

Comment: yes i tried re.search(r'hello'\(S*\w+)\?'), text). But it did'nt work. I read the file via d = open(file, 'r'; encoding="UTF-8") text = d.read()

Comment: it could be a good idea

Comment: Ok, so you read it in as a whole single string. You might try [`re.findall(r'(?m)^\s*Hello\s*([^?]+)', d)`](https://regex101.com/r/2fWFFt/1), but it is vulnerable (what if the contents contains `?`?).

Comment: Hint : dont use regexps, parse the text line by line. That's really basic text parsing stuff that doesn't require more than minimal programming skills and common sense.

Comment: thank you it works. At the beginning i'll use ths solution and look to cope with your other proposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask for is

```
re.findall(r'(?m)^\s*Hello\s*[^?]+', d)
```

where `d` is the whole file read in as a single string. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/2fWFFt/2). It is a bit vulnerable since it won't work correctly if the contents contains `?`.

I suggest reading line by line, checking if a line starts with `---` and then add the subsequent lines to a current record.

See the following [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7FiNfn):

```
items = []
tmp = ''
with open(file, 'r'; encoding="UTF-8") as d:
for line in d:
    if (line.strip().startswith('---')):
        if tmp:
            items.append(tmp.strip())
            tmp = ''
    else:
        tmp = tmp + line + "\n"
if tmp:
    items.append(tmp)

print(items)
```

Output:

```
['Hello\n\n During Test of mycomputerone following misconfiguration were detected\n - bad ip adress\n - bad name\n\n please could take the action to correct it and come back to us?', 
 'Hello\n\n During Test of mycomputertwo following misconfiguration were detected\n - bad ip adress\n - bad name\n - administrative share available\n\n please could take the action to correct it and come back to us?']
```

Comment: This will lost the last record if the file doesn't end with '---'.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have added `if tmp:  items.append(tmp)` so that the "tail" is appended to the `items` list.

Comment: thank you very much for the 2 solutions. I'll use the second one